# Align text input contents to right responsively

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I'm creating a custom input selector. It uses a text input to display the selection and a button for a user to make selection. It's similar to the snippet below:

```js
inputDisplay = document.getElementById("inputDisp");
choosePath = () => {
 const newpath = prompt("Enter new long path", "a/long/long/long/long/long/verylong/long/long/long/long/long/long/verylong/long/path/to/folder/");
 inputDisplay.value = newpath;
}

document.getElementById("btnSel").addEventListener("click", choosePath
);
```

```css
input {
  width:100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  input{
  text-align:right;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inputDisp" readonly value="a/path/to/a/folder/">
<button id="btnSel">Select path</button>
```

What I want is that as the user resizes the screen, it will align the text to the right if theres not enough space left to display the whole path. I thought I could use media queries, but if you input a short path and it aligns right, it does not look so good.

Is there a way I could align the contents of the input box to the right only when the text is too long for the textbox?

Comment: can you use `float:right` instead of `text-align`: right`

Comment: @Akshay, I'm trying to align the contents of the input box not the input box itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no css way to achieve your goal, because this would require to access the funtional layer instead of the presentation one. You still can manage to do this by using some javascript event handlers.

Just register a function which checks your inputs actual contained text length and toggles a css class with `text-align:right;` onto the `resize` event of your window and the `keydown` event of your input element.

See the DOM event documentation on w3school for more information about the events: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

You can check the current text length within the input like this:

```
 var value = document.getElementById('inputDisp').value;
 if (value.length > 20 && window.innerWidth <= 640) {
   // Toggle CSS class with text alignment right
 } else {
   // Toggle CSS class with text alignment left
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know not with pure css, with javascript you could hook onto several events and check the input string length against the input element width and align the latter's content to the right if the string is longer than its length. (window resize, input change)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `direction rtl/ltr` to solve this problem:

```js
inputDisplay = document.getElementById("inputDisp");
choosePath = () => {
 const newpath = prompt("Enter new long path", "a/long/long/long/long/long/verylong/long/long/long/long/long/long/verylong/long/path/to/folder/");
 inputDisplay.value = newpath;
}

document.getElementById("btnSel").addEventListener("click", choosePath
);
```

```css
input {
  direction: ltr;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  input{
    direction: rtl;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="inputDisp" readonly value="a/path/to/a/folder/">
<button id="btnSel">Select path</button>
```

Comment: incorrect, the op wanted only to align it to the right whenever the value of the input is actually longer than the input's width, and why would you not use text-align: right instead of changing its reading direction ..